# Impossible to install gettext for windows 10

Tags: python, django, gettext, xgettext

I have followed all the steps shared in all stackoverflow and other questions out there to install gettext for windows (10), but still, I get the error: "Can't find msguniq, make sure you have gettext tools installed" when using internationalization in django. I have tried to download the files directly and added them to the PATH, and even an installer that had already compiled everything and added to the path automatically, but it still doesn't work, and I don't know what else to do... Help please!

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I tried various solutions to no avail. Finally, I  downloaded the binaries from https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html
and it worked.

Comment: Can confirm, this method worked for me. If you don't know how to make sure you're using the updated PATH, you can restart your computer and that will definitely do it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what problem you face but below command worked for me

pip install python-gettext

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't work... manage.py makemessages -l es. 
CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.

Answer (score 0):

In windows you just need to download :

gettext-tools-xx.zip
gettext-runtime-xx.zip
from here: enter link description here

and then you need to unzip them and copy all in bin folder of both files into C:\Program Files\gettext-utils\bin and then you need to go to control panel-> system -> advanced -> environment variables and add this path:C:\Program Files\gettext-utils\bin to path variables. Note:

xx is the version you want to download if you download version 18 you will get an error that some dll file is missing, I suggest to download version 17
this folder: gettext-utils\bin does not exist and you need to create it
restart your pc before you use gettext